# how to make JOptionPane.showOptionDialog fit your screen

Tags: jpanel

```
String[] options = {"Adlawan", "Angeles", "Arreza", "Benenoso", "Bermas", "Brebante",       "Cabaylo", "C. Cainglet", "O. Cainglet",
                "Calunsag", "Cameros", "Casanaan", "Catulong", "Chicote", "Dela Paz", "Ea", "Echavez"};

int choose = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "                    WHICH EMPLOYEE'S     DATA WOULD YOU LIKE TO RESET?", "Click to One Choose ", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            option, option[16]);

if(choose == 0)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Ms. Adlawan is tall);
}

else if (choose == 1)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Mr. Angeles is old);
}
```

Those are my codes above.  Its running perfectly, if i run those codes, 17 buttons will appear and if i click "Adlawan" represented by (choose == 0) the message (Mrs. Adlawan is tall) appears and if i click "Angeles" represented by (choose == 1) the message (Mr. Angeles is old) appears.  The problem i have is that all 17 option does not fit the screen, how can i make those 17 option buttons fit the screen.  I've tried JPanel and adding JScrollPane to the panel and add those option buttons to the panel but it does not work.  Any help would be very much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`.

```
String selected = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    null,
                    "WHICH EMPLOYEE'S DATA WOULD YOU LIKE TO RESET?",
                    "Select One To Choose",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                    null, //icon
                    options ,
                    options[0]);

if(selected!=null){
  System.out.println("Selected option : " + selected); 
}
```